# ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter is not called

Tags: java, netty, nio

My server has few handlers

```
                            new ConnectionHandler(),
                            new MessageDecoder(),
                            new PacketHandler(),
                            new MessageEncoder()
```

It seems that last handler should be called when the server sends data to the client, but it never called.

Here is code of the handler

```
public class MessageEncoder extends ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("from encoder");
        NetCommand command = (NetCommand)msg;
        byte[] data = JsonSerializer.getInstance().Serialize(command);
        ByteBuf encoded = ctx.alloc().buffer(4+data.length);
        encoded.writeInt(data.length).writeBytes(data);
        ctx.writeAndFlush(encoded);
    }   
}
```

As you see i'm using POJO instead of ByteBuf, but it does not work. And even when I try to send ByteBuf the last handler is not called too.

Also here is how I send the data

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    Packet packet;
    NetCommand data;
    Session session;

    while ( isActive )
    {
        try {
            session = (Session) this.sessionQueue.take();
            packet = session.getWritePacketQueue().take();
            data =  packet.getData();
            System.out.println("data code: "+data.netCode);
            ChannelHandlerContext ctx = packet.getSender().getContext();
            ctx.writeAndFlush(data);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the `ChannelHandlerContext` you use for `writeAndFlush()` belongs to a `ChannelHandler` which is befor your last handler in the pipeline. If you want to ensure that the write starts at the tail / end of the pipeline use `ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(...)`